# How to change the connection string in App.config file for .edmx in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

I want to change initial catalog in App.Config connection string and add SQL Server Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [EntityConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) to do this.

Also, in your connection string add a `Persist Security Info=false` so that when you pull the connection string out, any security information is removed.